# ASP.NET C# Maior idade passada pela url

Tags: c#, asp.net

Seguinte, tenho uma página que recebe parâmetros de idade que podem variar em quantidade.

Exemplo:

> `url/page.aspx?idade=x&idade=y&idade=z`

Minha ideia é pegar todas as idades passadas pela `url` e selecionar apenas a maior, veja o código abaixo:

```
var idadePax = Request.QueryString["idade"];
var maxAge = idadePax.Max();
```

Porém, se eu passar **44**, **50** e **80** pela `url`, me retorna como maior o número **8**, tipo ele não reconhece a dezena **80** apenas o primeiro número como maior. Eu havia tentado utilizar

```
foreach(String n in idadePax) Int32.Parse(n)
```

para converter cada campo para inteiro, mas não consegui aplicar a lógica do maior para isso, se alguém puder me dar uma ajuda ou uma dica sobre em que estou pecando?

Comment: Se está usando web forms ou mvc?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic webform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando é feito uma requisição como demonstrado no seu exemplo é retornado na linha:

```
var idadePax = Request.QueryString["idade"];
```

um dado texto com os valores separados por virgula, exemplo:

```
44,50,80
```

Então precisa separar os dados (com o método [Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) que vai quebrar esse texto em um `array`) e com [linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) converter os dados e pegar o maior com [Max](http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-max/), *exemplo*:

```
if (Request.QueryString["idade"] != null)
{
    var idades = Request.QueryString["idade"];
    var idadeMax = idades.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).Max();
}
```

esse código só vai servir se os dados são sempre número, foi uma maneira de descrever que o retorno da sua `Request.QueryString` retorna um `string` com os dados separados por uma virgula.

Um maneira verificando se o dado realmente é um número:

```
if (Request.QueryString["idade"] != null)
{
    var idadeMax = int.MinValue;
    var idades = Request.QueryString["idade"];
    var idadesSplit = idades.Split(',');
    foreach (var item in idadesSplit)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out int n))
        {
            if (n > idadeMax) idadeMax = n;
        }
    }                
}
```

Comment: Nossa igual do javascript... @Virgilio Novic, só agradeço! Aqui funcionou perfeito. No caso eu estava passando a string inteira para o método Max() correto? ai quando uso o split ele transforma em um array e ai é possível verificar qual a idade é maior. é isso?

Comment: @MSHijo isso ... eu editei e coloque o link para leituras adicionais.